# Saving startup file does not effect startup

Tags: linux, startup-file

When I save my startup file using either `Ctrl+U` or `File -> Defaults -> Save Startup File`, the next time I open Blender, the original startup file opens.

I'm using Blender 2.82 on Ubuntu 20.04, and I downloaded Blender as a snap.

I'm assuming the issue is that the actual blender startup file isn't located at `~/.config/blender/2.82/config/startup.blend`.  When I look at this file manually, it is changing, and when I open it with blender, it is the file I'd like to open at startup, but this isn't what opens at startup.

Assuming that I'm correct, and it's actually using a different default location for the startup.blend, I searched for the file it's actually opening.  There are startup.blend files that exist in the following locations, but they don't appear to be what it's opening:

```
/snap/blender/37/2.82/scripts/startup/bl_app_templates_system/2D_Animation/startup.blend
/snap/blender/37/2.82/scripts/startup/bl_app_templates_system/Sculpting/startup.blend
/snap/blender/37/2.82/scripts/startup/bl_app_templates_system/VFX/startup.blend
/snap/blender/37/2.82/scripts/startup/bl_app_templates_system/Video_Editing/startup.blend
```

At this point, I'm either wrong about what the problem is, or I need to tell blender where to get its startup.blend from.

Blender is located at:

```
$ which blender
/snap/bin/blender
```

So the question is:
How do I edit my startup file, so that it holds the configuration, since the default doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's a bug of blender I reported [here](https://developer.blender.org/T78037), which already fixed in the current development branch and will be backported to 2.83 LTS version (fix included in version >= 2.83.4). For a workaround, after you do save your startup file, then navigate to preferences dialog and do any setting to get userpref.blend file generated in the blender user config folder, then it should works.

Answer (score -2):

You need to select the default settings (like whether to import previous keybindings, theme, etc) on the first splash screen, then you will be able to set your default file.